# How to create a Microstrategy Plugin

Tags: javascript, sdk, microstrategy

i'm an absolute beginner about microstrategy.

i find this code for a plugin:
https://gist.github.com/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6
Now i'm trying to set up correctly the plugin folder with microstrategy customization web, to show correctly the plugin.

I create a new plugin with the customization web. 
Then i go to the MicroStrategy\Web ASPx\plugins\mypluginName folder and i add a javascript folder with inside the .js file.

Where i have to put the index.html file?!
i can't able to find anything about it in the documentation, so someone can give me more information about the question? 
My priority are to solve this issue, but in future i'll have to  handling better this arguments, so i need to read something about it (a link is very appreciate)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find all the information you need here :
https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Custom-Visualization-Gallery/bg-p/vizgallery